# Is there any way to connect Einstein analytics to some 3rd party BI applications such as powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, salesforce, business-intelligence, attribution, salesforce-einstein

Is there any way to connect Einstein analytics to some 3rd party BI applications such as powerbi? I am working on a one stop dashboard in PowerBI which should have data from multiple sources and I was wondering if I can include the einstein analytics attribution model in the same dashboard to have a one stop solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Einstein datasets cannot be directly connected to PowerBI. Alternatively, you can connect to salesforce objects and replicate the same dataset using powerquery. There is also a catch here. When you connect salesforce object to power bi, scheduled refreshes doesn't work due to some limitations between salesforce and power bi. You would have to manually refresh from powerbi desktop and then publish your report to power bi service.